# Arithmetic operations on BigInteger in Java

Tags: java, biginteger

How to use BigInteger objects for computation and in for loops? Presuming I have to find the largest prime less than a given number, how do I make a loop run between 2 and the large number? It exceeds the maximum size of int and long data types by far.

Comment: Your answer is, as usual, in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html). If you have queries about a class, that's usually the place to find your answers.

Comment: what you are asking is unclear. follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

So if what you're looking for is to iterate a loop that has numbers bigger than integers go, you could try something like this.

```
for(BigInteger i = BigInteger.ZERO; i < *your big number here*; i= i.add(BigInteger.ONE){
      //whatever you're looking to do
}
```

That should work

Comment: As `BigInteger`s are immutable, ignoring the result of a call to `add()` means that call does _nothing_. The correct form for the third part of the loop is `i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)` - note that `BigInteger.ONE` also is generally more readable than a `valueOf()` call. The same goes for `BigInteger.ZERO`, which you can use in the first clause of your `for` loop. -1 for not checking your code's correctness, but I will remove it if you make an edit to fix the mistake.

Comment: Thanks for catching that!

Comment: You're still not using the result of `add()`. `i = i.add(BigInteger.ONE)`, not just the call to `add()`.

Comment: *Throws computer out window* Thanks again!

Comment: In Java, which does not have operator overloading, the `<` will not work for BigIntegers. You'll have to use `compare()`.